# wholesale and retail site same inventory

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have magento 1.9, I am new to Magento but can get around in the backend, if possible please provide some step by step

We have 2 domains i.e. retail.com & wholesale.com one for wholesale and one for retail.

We want the inventory to be shared between the two stores

I want the home page and the theme to be different between the sites.

the wholesale site should not have purchase possibility it should function like a catalog

is this possible? is it in the manage store area? Again  I am new to Magento but can get around in the backend, if possible please provide some step by step thanks

Comment: You need to break this question down to several separate questions, but the general answer is that you can do what you're describing. Magento has only one inventory pool, and you can easily make products not purchasable for a website.

Answer (score 1):

Well first off I'd recommend checking out this tutorial on how to setup the stores: http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

You'll want to follow the add-on domain method.

That will let you share items amongst websites, you'll just have to make sure products are added to both websites (when setting up items).

Why are you looking to disable purchasing on your wholesale site? You can setup a wholesale price level to your wholesale accounts so they can see wholesale pricing.

Comment: Since our in stock levels aren't an accurate representation of what can be ordered im concerned that our wholesale customers won't see everything that is available to be back ordered. si there an alternate way of enabling wholesale customers to back order items?

Comment: Yes, you would have this ability. Since they will be separate sites, you'll be able to edit the configuration settings separately. The retail website you will tell it to NOT allow backorders, while the wholesale website you will just enable backorders in the inventory settings.

Comment: System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options: Backorders set to No Backorders for retail.